# Problem of getting documentId when trying to track different users' geolocations with angular cloud firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I'm new to firebase cloud firestore. What i'm trying to do is tracking logged-in users' geolocations using google-maps API. 
There are lots of questions but the most confusing is how to get ducument id that generated automatically and how to set document id automaically? Here is the part of the code:

```
updateGeolocation(uuid,lat,lng){
    if(localStorage.getItem('userLocations')){
      this.locRef.doc().update({
        deviceID: uuid,
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng
      })
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userLocations'))
      .then(function() {
        console.log("Document successfully updated.");
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
      });
    }else{
      let newData = this.locRef.doc().set({
        deviceID: uuid,
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng
      },{merge: true});
      localStorage.setItem('userLocations', JSON.stringify(newData));
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userLocations'));
    }
 }
```

For example, I have no idea what should I put in "this.locRef.doc(???)". Maybe I could put "uuid" in it but when I use navigator it was "null" and fail. I have looked in official document and looks like we can leave it blank(doc()) and it will generate a automatic id but in this way I got errors. Someone could help me please?

Comment: If this part of code is not enough just let me know pls and I will post more so that you guys could understand better my question!

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) is pretty clear:

> When you use set() to create a document, you must specify an ID for
>   the document to create
>
> But sometimes there isn't a meaningful ID for the document, and it's
>   more convenient to let Cloud Firestore auto-generate an ID for you.
>   You can do this by calling add()

And then regarding `update`:

> To update some fields of a document without overwriting the entire
>   document, use the update() method

(Calling update on a non-existing doc will fail)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! So I change the "doc().set()" to "add()" and it will generate a new document with meaningless id. But since this is a tracking geolocations function(I put it in geolocation.watchPosition()) I have to update the content of the document all the time, so how can I get this new-generated document with it's meaningless id and update it? Thanks again!

Comment: Use an id with a meaning then! Like you user id

Comment: Tks! I've thought about this idea like "this.afs.collection("userLocations").doc(user.uid).set" but this "user" is an array o an Observable data o something else because there are more than one user? How coud I generate this "user"? Sorry for this maybe stupid question I'm pretty confused as a newer in firestore

Comment: This last bit has nothing to do with Firestore. You store the location of an entity, be it a user, a group or whatever - you need to be able to give it an id if you want to retrieve it later...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to track a single location for each user, and your user is identified by the `uuid`. In that case it makes most sense to use the `uuid` value as the ID for those documents, instead of letting Firestore generate an auto-id for it.

Something like:

```
updateGeolocation(uuid,lat,lng){
    if(localStorage.getItem('userLocations')){
      this.locRef.doc(uuid).update({
        deviceID: uuid,
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng
      })
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userLocations'))
      .then(function() {
        console.log("Document successfully updated.");
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
      });
    }else{
      let newData = this.locRef.doc(uuid).set({
        deviceID: uuid,
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng
      },{merge: true});
      localStorage.setItem('userLocations', JSON.stringify(newData));
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userLocations'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Tks! Yes, I've tried this method before and it maked sense to me. But since I'm making a web app, when I run the app in the navigator, the device uuid is naturally "null", and with the "null" in doc(null) I got error like "it has to be a non-empty string but got null". So I test it in a android mobile but shows nothing in the map. I wandar if the problem is from localstorage? Runs igually in web page and in devices? Tell me how do u think Frank pls

Comment: Each document needs some way to identify it, otherwise you can't ever find it. So how would you later be able to find the document for that browser/session if it doesn't have a UUID? And if you can't find it in any way, should you really be storing the location when there's no UUID yet? These are all just questions to direct you towards the proper data structure btw, as I don't know enough about your use-case to answer them.

Comment: `import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device/ngx';
watch.subscribe((data)=>{ this.updateGeolocation(this.device.uuid,data.coords.latitude,data.coords.longitude);})`           Basically I'm using device package of ionic and passing every single device uuid to the function above. And in firestore I have a user collection with (uid,uuid,email,displayName,etc) and a userLocations collection with (uuid,lat,lng). Could u so kindly tell me am I doing it in a right way?

Answer (score 0):

For details on getting data with Cloud Firestore, you may take a look at [Get data with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) documentation page.

Comment: Tks for info! I guess what makes me confused is the geolocation.watchPosition.subscribe. It updates location info like a loop so that I have to get the document id that was created previously in firestore. With single set/add/update I got it but with all mixed up I cannot firgue out the logic...